# Apache rewrite all paths to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to rewrite paths like:

```
/xyz/ijk?a=b&c=d
```

to index.php:

```
/index.php/xyz/ijk?a=b&c=d
```

But with variable PATH_INFO = /xyz/ijk as it's when i don't use rewrite (/index.php/xyz/ijk?a=b&c=d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA ]
```