# show index.php on every html or php url, without changing url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

show index.php on every html or php url, without changing url

ex. user type anything-everything.html(.php) will show index.php without changing url,

condition - anything-everything.html(.php) not present on the host

like 404 redirect withoutchanging url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. If you're running your website on an Apache webserver, you can use the [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to achieve this. Here's an example of an `.htaccess` file, that you have to place in the root of your website.

```
# switch on mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# redirect all non-www request to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# rewrite all physical files and folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# add all exceptions that should not be redirected
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/layout/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/javascript/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/content"

# and finally pass everything to the index.php as a parameter
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?value=$1 [QSA]
```

This will do the following:

- if the user requests **http://domain.com** he will be forwared to **http://www.domain.com**
- the request **domain.com/hello/world.html** will end up in the index.php file with an existing `$_GET['value']` that holds `hello/world.html`, which can then be processed further

Comment: working but show same echo for every page need different php echo according urls

Comment: @kritprim Sorry, I don't really understand your comment. Do you mean, you need a different PHP file for every request, like `/hello` will be redirected to `hello.php`?

Comment: php file for echo urlof currunt page

Comment: need echo different for allpages

Comment: ex. this is php <?php 
echo ucfirst(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME));
?>

Comment: @kritprim Let's take the example from above: Calling `domain.com/hello` will be redirected to `index.php`. In this file you can simply do `print $_GET['value'];` which will output *hello* based on that you can also do `if ('hello' == $_GET['value']) include 'hello_logic.php';`.

Comment: this php contaons my index.php, show page name for every current page but after htaccess redirect show same echo for all as "index"

Comment: @kritprim Also take a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Answer (score 0):

Use apache rewrite (if you use apache and have access to server).
recipe from [Apache rewrite all paths to index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965226/apache-rewrite-all-paths-to-index-php) should be ok.