# Call "index.php" in all page

Tags: php

My website configuration is :

```
L index.php
L assets
  L all my files like css/js...
L views
  L page1.php
  L page2.php
```

My index read the url, take the information after the "/", and he load the right view in "views".
But when I'm calling another page, I'm using a `<a href='page1.php'>`

When I click on the link, my url is like : mydomain.com/page1.php, my website try to load the page1.php but it doesn't exist at the website racine.
I want that my website load the index.php, in it, "page1.php" is watching then the right view can be loaded.

How can I do it without my 404 error...

Actually, when I'm clicking on a link, the index isn't called so all the time I have the 404 error.

Comment: You will either need to link to a different target then - something like `index.php?page=page1` - or look into some basic _URL rewriting_.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you need a routing engine. Or just simplify your design and put all the view files in the top-level folder

Comment: I was thinking about it but don't want to use un get and I wanted to have my index as a "controller"

Comment: If you don't use URL rewriting a file must exist in the exact location the URL specifies. htaccess is a common solution, for example download Drupal and look up how they do it.

Comment: I wanted to do it with the .htaccess but I don't know why, I got a lot of error
I tried to modify the DirectoyIndex by my index but it doesn't work

Comment: @Lucas maybe [Apache rewrite all paths to index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965226/apache-rewrite-all-paths-to-index-php) or [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules) will help.

Answer (score 1):

use the following code :

```
require_once('index.php');
```

Comment: It's useless
I don't want to import it in my file, I want that all my request are redirect in my index
My index have a routing function to call the right view

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).